# Common lisp: break, but return input instead of nil?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new to lisp, and am learning as I go.

The standard common lisp break function 1. pops you into the debugger, and 2. if you choose to continue, returns nil.

It seems to me that a break function that popped you into the debugger but RETURNED ITS INPUT would be extremely useful.  Then, you could just insert it transparently around a given s-expression to look at the state of the program at that point.

So I could do something like

```
CL-USER> (break-transparent (+ 1 2))
```

which would pop me into the debugger and let me look around and then would return

```
3
```

Is there such a thing in lisp, and, if not, is there a way to make such a thing?  I am not good with macros yet.

Thanks,

EDIT:
Doug Currie kindly answered this below with a simple macro.  Here is my slightly modified version for anyone else with this question that displays the argument to break-transparent front and center in the debugger window.

```
(defmacro break-transparent (exp)
  `(let ((x ,exp)) (break "argument to break: ~:S" x) x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `break-transparent` as a macro that expands to:

```
(progn
  (break)
  (+ 1 2))
```

or if you really want to evaluate the expression before the break:

```
(let ((x (+ 1 2)))
  (break)
  x)
```

So,

```
(defmacro (break-transparent exp)
  `(let ((x ,exp)) (break) x))
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  I changed it a little bit so that break would display its argument in the debugger window without having to go hunt for "x" in the backtrace.  `(defmacro break-transparent (exp)
  \`(let ((x ,exp)) (break "argument to break: ~:S" x) x))`  .  (break-transparent (+ 1 2)) produces the output "argument to break: 3" in the debugger window and returns 3.

Comment: Introducing a new identifier `x` in a macro is bad. It might interfere with an existing `x`. Use `gensym` to create an identifier that's guaranteed to be unique instead.

Comment: The new identifier `x` only interferes with code in the body of the let, not the `exp`; the body of the let is fully under our control, so there is no existing `x` to interfere with. Normally I would use `gensym` in any case, but it only complicates the answer.

Comment: @DougCurrie: True, it's hard to imagine a case where this would be a problem, but it's still possible, for example if the `break-transparent` is included in the argument forms to a code-walking macro that replaces all occurrences of `x` with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've added the macro from the other answer to your question in a slightly modified version, here's a fixed version of that that doesn't add a new identifer that might interfere with an existing one:

```
(defmacro break-transparent (value)
  (let ((g (gensym)))
    `(let ((,g ,value))
      (break "argument to break: ~:S" ,g)
      ,g)))
```